# @JsonIgnore does not ignore fields in hibernate Entity

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

I have an Entity "Task" that has an Id property, but I don't need the field to be returned in the JSON file.

```
@Entity
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer Id;
    @JsonProperty("task")
    private String taskName;

    private String status;
    //getter and setter
}
```

However, the annotation @JsonIgnore doesn't filter the field when I make the get request, see below:

```
{
    "status": "started",
    "timestamps": {
        "submitted": "2018-12-31T00:34:20.718+0000",
        "started": "2018-12-31T00:34:20.718+0000",
        "completed": "2018-12-31T00:34:20.718+0000"
    },
    "id": 40001,
    "task": "q094hiu3o"
}
```

What is the proper way to prevent "Id" to be displayed?

Comment: try adding that on getter method

Comment: @Deadpool It already has all getters and setters.

Comment: i mean add that annotation on Getter method and try it

Comment: one more thing i observed case difference `private Integer Id;` and `"id": 40001,`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here is the problem `jackson` had issue with `hibernate` [issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1317), try using `@jsonIgnoreProperties` on class level

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, 
                  value = {"id"})
```

Comment: Good to know that there may be bugs around these approaches, I usually use the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` just to ignore unknown

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add the `@JsonIgnore` only on your getter:

```
    @JsonIgnore
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

Also I would suggest to add the `@JsonProperty` annotation on your id field, if it is available in the Jackson version you are using:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private Integer id;
```

> WRITE_ONLY
>   Access setting that means that the property may only be written (set) for deserialization, but will not be read (get) on serialization, that is, the value of the property **is not included in serialization**.

[Jackson documentation here](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.Access.html)

Comment: Perhaps you're confusing serialization with deserialization.