# @JsonIgnoreProperties JPA - Not ignoring properties

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am having a faq entity as below. Here createdBy field is having a manyToOne relationship with the user entity. Below joinColumns shows the association.
In the User entity, i have OneToMany relationship with UserRoles and UsersUnit which is EAGER load for User and not for faq. So i added @JsonIgnoreProperties
for UsersUnit and UsersRole and the corresponding User entity is shown below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FAQ", catalog="abc")
public class Faq implements Serializable {
    public Faq() {
        super();
    }
    
    @Column(name = "CREATE_DATE")
    private Timestamp createDate;
    @Where(clause = "DELETE_DATE is null")
    @Column(name = "DELETE_DATE")
    private Timestamp deleteDate;
    @Column(name = "DELETED_BY")
    private BigDecimal deletedBy;
    @Column(name = "DOC_BLOB", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private byte[] docBlob;
    @Column(name = "DOC_NAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String docName;
    @Id
    private BigDecimal id;
    
    @Column(name = "ORDER_BY")
    private BigDecimal orderBy;
    
    @Column(name = "UPDATE_DATE")
    private Timestamp updateDate;
    @Column(name = "UPDATED_BY")
    private BigDecimal updatedBy;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id")
    })
    private User faqCreatedBy;
   
}
```

User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS", catalog="abc")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class User extends EntityLog{
    
    private BigDecimal id;
    private BigDecimal edipi;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    ..///
    
    private Set<UsersRoles> userRoles;
    private Set<UsersUnit> usersUnit;
    
        @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    public BigDecimal getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    
    ...///
        @Column
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "faqCreatedBy" })
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "user",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JsonManagedReference
    public Set<UsersRoles> getUserRoles() {
            return userRoles;
    }
        
        
        
        ...///
    
        @Column
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "faqCreatedBy" })
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "user",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JsonManagedReference
    public Set<UsersUnit> getUsersUnit() {
        return usersUnit;
    }
    
    ////...
    
    }
```

With this change I am expecting the faq to load with User entity but I am not execting UsersRoles and UsersUnit to load.
But that is not what i see. When faq loads it loads User and UsersRoles and UsersUnit. I am using Spring JPA fyi. Any leads what is wrong ? Appreciate any inputs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@JsonIgnore does not ignore fields in hibernate Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53982623/jsonignore-does-not-ignore-fields-in-hibernate-entity)

Comment: IMHO the root of the problem is violating separation of concerns. Here the concerns are "data transfer" and "persistence", both implemented in the same object. This happens way too often, unfortunately. I always use separate DTOs and Entities, even though there is some extra pain for the conversion. Anyway, if your assumption is that if you annotate e.g. `getUserRoles` with `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"faqCreatedBy"})` Jackson will not access this field if loaded through the `faqCreatedBy` property, I think this is not how `JsonIgnoreProperties` works!